# How to get clicked span inside div and modify its preceding spans and successor spans with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div>
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
<span>C</span>
<span>D</span>
</div>
```

If user clicks on a span, i need to apply styles(text colour) on that span and all preceding span inside that div. And to remove the previous clicked span doings also. The span has no class and id.

How can i achieve this using J Query?

Comment: use `this` context with `.prev()` and `.next()`

Comment: this + .siblings()

Comment: Yes i did tried a lot and also searched. But was not able to find a solution. Sorry for not attaching  JSfiddle as it was a simple one and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all previous sibling elements of clicked element you can use `prevAll()` but to also include clicked element you need to add `andSelf()`. Also you first need to remove background from all `span`'s every time you click on `span`.

```js
$('div span').click(function() {
  $('div span').css('background', 'none');
  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().css('background', 'red')
})
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow you always learn something new, great and simple way to solve that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5 You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s01jmt8n/) fiddle code helps.

**JS:**

```
$('span').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().css('color','')
    $(this).css('color','red');
  $(this).prevAll().css( "color", "red" );
});
```